# How can i fix my error occured in this code about josephus problem

Tags: python, doubly-linked-list

i want to use circulardoublylinkedlist to solve josephus problem.

```
    def __init__(self, item, prev = None, next = None):
        self.item = item
        self.prev = prev
        self.next = next

class CircularDoublyLinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.head is None

    def clear(self):
        self.head = None

    def addFront(self, item):
        newNode = DNode(item)
        if self.isEmpty():
            self.head = newNode
            self.head.prev = newNode
            self.head.next = newNode

        else:
            newNode.prev = self.head.prev
            newNode.next = self.head
            self.head.prev.next = newNode
            self.head.prev = newNode
            self.head = newNode

    def addRear(self, item):
        newNode = DNode(item)
        if self.isEmpty():
            self.head = newNode
            self.head.prev = newNode
            self.head.next = newNode
        else:
            newNode.prev = self.head.prev
            self.head.prev.next = newNode
            newNode.next = self.head
            self.head.prev = newNode

    def deleteFront(self):
        if not self.isEmpty():
            data = self.head.item
            count = self.size()
            if count == 1:
                self.head = None
            else:
                self.head.next.prev = self.head.prev
                self.head.prev.next = self.head.next
                self.head = self.head.next
            return data

    def deleteRear(self):
        if not self.isEmpty():
            data = self.head.prev.item
            count = self.size()
            if count == 1:
                self.head = None
            else:
                self.head.prev = self.head.prev.prev
                self.head.prev.next = self.head

            return data

    def size(self):
        if self.head is None:
            return 0
        count = 1
        tmp = self.head
        while tmp is not self.head.prev:
            count += 1
            tmp = tmp.next
        return count

    def peekFront(self):
        if not self.isEmpty():
            return self.head.item

    def peekRear(self):
        if not self.isEmpty():
            return self.head.prev.item
        
    def print(self):
        if not self.isEmpty():
            ptr = self.head.next
            print(self.head.item, end = " ")
            while ptr is not self.head:
                print(ptr.item, end = " ")
                ptr = ptr.next
        print()  

    def revPrint(self):
        ptr = self.head.prev
        while ptr is not self.head:
            print(ptr.item, end = " ")
            ptr = ptr.prev
        print(self.head.item)
        print()

    def josephus(self, where):
        self_size = self.size()
        # print(self.head.item)
        # print("size : ", self.size())
        while self_size > 1:
            for _ in range(where-1):
                self.head = self.head.next
                # print(self.head.item)
                # print("size :", self.size())
            self.deleteFront()
        if self_size == 1:
            print(self.head.item, "is alive")


def main():
    dq = CircularDoublyLinkedList()
    print("Enter a command: af(addFront), df(deleteFront), pf(peekFront), s(size)")
    print("ar(addRear), dr(deleteRear), pr(peekRear), rp(reversePrint)")
    print("j(josephus problem - enter kth number to be out: ), or q(uit)")
    while True:
        line = input().split()
        command = line[0]
        if command == 'af':
            item = line[1]
            dq.addFront(item)
        elif command == 'j':
            item = line[1]
            dq.josephus(int((item)))
        elif command == 'df':
            print(dq.deleteFront())
        elif command == 'pf':
            print(dq.peekFront())
        elif command == 'ar':
            item = line[1]
            dq.addRear(item)
        elif command == 'dr':
            print(dq.deleteRear())
        elif command == 'pr':
            print(dq.peekRear())
        elif command == 'p':
            dq.print()
        elif command == 'rp':
            dq.revPrint()
        elif command == 's':
            print("size : ", dq.size())
        elif command == 'q':
            break


main()
```

This is my code, and I tested with these lines:

```
print(self.head.item)
print("size : ", self.size())
```

and

```
print(self.head.item)
print("size :", self.size())
```

but AttributeError occured. It says 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next'. but I don't understand because I put 10 numbers in it, so self.head should not be `None`... it points to the first input... what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably in your loop:

```
    def josephus(self, where):
        self_size = self.size()
        # print(self.head.item)
        # print("size : ", self.size())
        while self_size > 1:
            for _ in range(where-1):
                self.head = self.head.next
                # print(self.head.item)
                # print("size :", self.size())
            self.deleteFront()
        if self_size == 1:
            print(self.head.item, "is alive")
```

When the loop starts, self_size = 10, and nowhere are you changing self_size during the loop.  So it just keeps running and calling deleteFront() until self.head is set to None.  Then the next iteration tries to reference `self.head.next` and you get this exception.